# How to play interactive flash animations on iPad?

Tags: flash, ipad

I am trying to get the solutions from last month but no better luck. I have created interactive 500 animations in flash using CS3 and action script 2.0. Now i want to play these on iPad.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Does the application have to run in a browser or native? In browser will never work since Flash Player is not supported on iOS. However an AIR application can be cross compiled to a native iOS application. It is very hard to answer a question which is not specific enough to answer. Try to take care of that.

Comment: It may be native or browser application. Doesnt matter.

Comment: In browser won't work, so use Jason Sturges' approach and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You must package your applications as Apps:

Internet is full of tutorials:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/packaging-air-apps-ios.html

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/packaging-air-apps-android.html

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/packaging-air-apps-blackberry.html

For iOS, you will need to enroll in Apple's iOS Developer Program and access the Provisioning Profile for needed certificates.

You can also package your SWF using the ADT command line packager.

Download AIR 3.0 SDK.
Assure JRE, or use the one from Flash Builder.
Execute adt to package your SWF to an IPA:

```
adt -package -target [ipa-test | ipa-debug | ipa-app-store | ipa-ad-hoc]
    -keystore iosPrivateKey.p12 -storetype pkcs12 -storepass qwerty12
    -provisioning-profile ios.mobileprovision
    HelloWorld.ipa
    HelloWorld-app.xml
    HelloWorld.swf icons Default.png
```

Comment: I have tried Flash Builder 4.5 and done all things. It runs on iPad but speed and quality of flash is unacceptable.

Comment: Flash Builder 4.5 came with AIR 2.6 packager.  AIR 3.0 SDK have made significant improvements to performance.  Make sure you are following best practices, as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881221/building-an-ios-app-with-adobe-flex-builder-performance-issues/7881298#7881298

Answer (score 1):

Flash Professional CS5.5 has iOS export functionality. It creates an app from your code that can be played on iPad or iPhone.

It's AS3 only, but it's a lot easier to port an application to a different ActionScript version than to a completely new environment.

You'll also need an Apple developer account.

Here's a video showing the whole process, from a Flash file to a working iOS app:

http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=116

Comment: THe iOS export function has been available since pre CS5, just sayin.

Comment: What about the quality and interactivity of the animations?

Answer (score 0):

You must package your applications as Apps:

Internet is full of tutorials:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/packaging-air-apps-ios.html

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/packaging-air-apps-android.html

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/packaging-air-apps-blackberry.html

For iOS, you will need to enroll in Apple's iOS Developer Program and access the Provisioning Profile for needed certificates.

You can also package your SWF using the ADT command line packager.

Download AIR 3.0 SDK.
Assure JRE, or use the one from Flash Builder.
Execute adt to package your SWF to an IPA:

```
adt -package -target [ipa-test | ipa-debug | ipa-app-store | ipa-ad-hoc]
    -keystore iosPrivateKey.p12 -storetype pkcs12 -storepass qwerty12
    -provisioning-profile ios.mobileprovision
    HelloWorld.ipa
    HelloWorld-app.xml
    HelloWorld.swf icons Default.png
```

Same as above

Comment: I have Apple's iOS Developer Program and Provisioning profile. I will do it. thanks for the help.