# Flash AS3 - Adding reflection/mirror to draggable movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, reflection, drag, mirror

I am needing to create a flash file that creates pattern shapes from just 1 image. It needs to reflect or mirror a loaded draggable movieclip - with the reflection/mirror updating as you move and drag the movieclip around the stage.

I had come across: http://active.tutsplus.com/freebies/actionscript-30-classes/dynamic-reflection-generator-class-for-as3/
which does very similar to what i'm after. The demo seems ok but as in the comments there is lots of slowdown and lag in the dragging, especially when the image you drag starts off larger.

Sorry for asking for what seems quite a bit, i'm not after the complete solution, i just need to know firstly if it can be done and how i can go about achieving it?

I'm hoping the following images can help explain:

**Stage 1:**
Loading the users pattern image onto the stage as seen here:

http://www.tiltworld.co.uk/yhfus6fh/pattern_1.png

**Stage 2:**
Shows how i want the reflection to work - in 4 blocks on each side of the pattern:

.../pattern_2.png

(same link as the above just with pattern_2.png at the end)

**Stage 3:**
Getting the reflection to adapt to where the user drags the pattern around on the stage. As in the image the reflection happens within the 4 blocks on each side rather than attached directly onto/next to the original movieclip.

..../pattern_3.png

(same link as the 2 above just with pattern_3.png at the end)

Lauren :)

p.s. My current code below shows currently Stage 1 -  how i load the pattern onto the stage using fileReference.load and then startDrag to drag it around the stage.

```
// Create FileReference.
var draggableMC:FileReference;

// Create Loader to hold image content
var draggable_mc_loader:Loader = new Loader();
var draggable_mc_content:Sprite = new Sprite();

// Select Button Function.
select_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onselect_btnClicked);

function onselect_btnClicked(event:MouseEvent):void {
draggableMC=new FileReference();
draggableMC.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelected);
var imageTypeFilter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("JPG/PNG Files","*.jpeg; *.jpg;*.gif;*.png");
draggableMC.browse([imageTypeFilter]);
}

// File Selected Function.
function onFileSelected(event:Event):void {
draggableMC.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoaded);
draggableMC.load();
}

// File Loaded Function.
function onFileLoaded(event:Event):void {
var fileReference:FileReference=event.target as FileReference;

var data:ByteArray=fileReference["data"];
var movieClipLoader:Loader=new Loader();
movieClipLoader.loadBytes(data);
movieClipLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onMovieClipLoaderComplete);

draggableMC.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoaded);
}

// Load Image onto Stage Function.
function onMovieClipLoaderComplete(event:Event):void {
var loadedContent:DisplayObject=event.target.content;
draggable_mc_loader =event.target.loader as Loader;
draggable_mc_loader.x=10;
draggable_mc_loader.y=10;
draggable_mc_content.buttonMode=true;
draggable_mc_content.addChild(draggable_mc_loader);
addChild(draggable_mc_content);
}

// Drag
draggable_mc_content.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);

function drag(event:Event):void {
draggable_mc_content.startDrag();
}
function drop(event:Event):void {
draggable_mc_content.stopDrag();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can totally be done, have you tried using his component.  In looking at the code in the fla attached to the component you linked he's having it update on MouseMove which isn't ideal, multiple move events can be dispatched in a single frame loop (default frame rate I believe is 24 so every 1/24th of a second would be a frame loop and the updates based on MouseMove will be unnecessarily fast).  If it was simply adjusted to turn on a timer that ticked every 10th of a second after the object is clicked (mouse down then turned off on mouse up, or roll out), instead of trying to do it for every mouse move event it would improve the performance significantly.  Further he's got quite a few inefficiencies in the code, and as he stated whatever he put it out there for free if you need it optimized for some task then optimize it.  Some other inefficiencies in his code are the creation of objects within the method calls that could be pulled into the constructor and the usage of filters where in your example these don't seem to be necessary.  Just stumbled on this post on AS3 optimization earlier today checking out Jason Sturges profile [What are the major performance hitters in AS3 aside from rendering vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380789/what-are-the-major-performance-hitters-in-as3-aside-from-rendering-vectors/8380883#8380883)