# Does the Flash Text Engine display faster than typical TextFields?

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, flash, text, textfield

In this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8380883/1294758) they have recommended using the Flash Text Engine (FTE) text objects like TextLine and TextBlock for read-only text. They said its faster than using the typical TextField class. However in a speedtest, you can clearly see that TextFields render faster than their FTE counterparts. Why is this? In which case does FTE text objects perform better than TextFields? Of course the FTE text objects look prettier since they have better anti-aliasing, but they are rendering slower.

See the speedtests here:

- [Flash Text Engine](http://www.swfcabin.com/open/1367400182) - 500 TextLines
- [TextField](http://www.swfcabin.com/open/1367400226) - 500 TextFields

I'm just creating 500 text objects and repositioning them all per frame. This is what I'm doing, in pseudo code. Its literally a 10 line program so there can be nothing "wrong" with the code.

```
at init
    500 times
        create FTE/TF object and store in array

per frame (enterFrame event)
    per text object
        increment .x and .y position, wrapped within stage
```

Comment: The SO post you linked to says FTE has less memory usage and better rendering - there is no mention of speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely not true. There is **no case** where FTE is faster than TextField. FTE attempts to render text more nicely and have more features than TextField. This, in turn, makes it slower. A lot slower.

I spent half a year writing a TLF clone. I could never get past the bad FTE performance or bugs.

Comment: And to think having "lower level access to text rendering" in Flash meant it could go faster! ...

Comment: "I spent half a year writing a TLF clone." - perhaps you wish to share your knowledge? If so, please contact me at `broadysmile (at) gmail.com` . One of things I'm trying to find out right now is: is there any character creating more than 1 atom, or any combination of characters creating less atoms than characters (except ligatures).

Answer (score 3):

From my experience regular TextFields are much faster than FTE text

Answer (score 2):

That post is quoting [these Adobe docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS4bebcd66a74275c3-576ba64d124318d7189-7ff5.html).

It says that FTE:

> ...offers low memory usage and better rendering.

It doesn't say "faster" rendering, it says "better" -- which I take to mean better quality.